# Implement a function that swaps a 32-bit integer "byte-wise" using PHP and/or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, byte, mask, swap

I am a front-end developer and uses JavaScript/PHP a lot. I would appreciate if someone could give me the solution and help me explain it (if not very time consuming).

```
function byte_swap() {
   // implementation
   return 0;
}

byte_swap(0x12345678)

// Expected output
0x78563412
```

I read up online about "mask and shift strategy", but couldn't understand it :( I also couldn't find the solution with this strategy in JS/PHP.

If there are other better strategies than "mask and shift strategy", I would like to explore them as well.

Thanks a lot in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is sample code which first extracts each byte into separate variable and then reconstruct 32 bit integer back

```js
function byte_to_hex(b) {
   let s = b.toString(16);
   return b > 0xf ? s : "0" + s;
}

function byte_swap(t) {
   let a = t & 0xff;
   let b = (t >> 8) & 0xff;
   let c = (t >> 16) & 0xff;
   let d = (t >> 24) & 0xff;
   return byte_to_hex(a) + byte_to_hex(b) + byte_to_hex(c) + byte_to_hex(d);
}

console.log('0x' + byte_swap(0x12345678));
console.log('0x' + byte_swap(0xFF85));
```

Comment: The bitmask on a and d is superfluous, and b and c are shifted twice which can be joined into one operation. `(t << 24) | ((t << 8) & 0xff0000) | ((t >> 8) & 0xff00) | (t >> 24)`

Comment: Thank you @Iłya Bursov. Your code does give the expected value. Would you mind if I ask you how does this code works and how did you get these 8,16, 24 etc number ?

Comment: @user1704440 this code extracts each bit via bitwise operations (you can read about them in any js tutorial), numbers are just number of bits, ie 8-16-24

Comment: Found this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp which goes over the basics. Since it is HEX, is that the reason to pick multiples of 8 and stopped at 24? Apologies for my ignorance in this domain.

Comment: @user1704440 no, reason is that byte is 8 bit, so to extract bytes you need to use multiples of 8

Comment: What does extract really means in this context? Could you share a high level pseudocode in plan text ?

Comment: @user1704440 javascript is already very high level language, almost pseudo code, higher is only words like "extract first byte" - which is obviously not enough for you. `let a = t & 0xff;` extracts most right byte from integer by setting bits 9-32 to zero via bitwise &

Comment: @Iłya Bursov Thank you very much for all the help. With the help of lot of console.logs and debugger, I was finally able to reverse engineer this solution and understood the implementation.

If the question was bit-wise, then we will start with multiples of 4 instead of 8. Correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233534/discussion-between-user1704440-and-ilya-bursov).